# xxx.h: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'yyyy.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am working with a c project, where I need to include a header file which has few other header files. When I tried to compile compiler is also looking for header files included in the header file I am using.

To be more clear, I am need of using `xxx.h` file in my current program which has only one useful function to me. But `xxx.h` file got some other `yyy.h` included in it.
When I compile I am having the below error:

> `xxx.h`: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: `yyy.h`: No such file or directory

Anyone can please suggest me a way to include `xxx.h` file and use the only one function I need  with including `yyy.h` to my current project?

Comment: You need to modify the include path for your project. How to do that depends on your compiler: From the format of the error message, it looks like you're using some variant of MSVS. Check the documentation on how to modify your include path to include the path of yyy.h

Comment: I am using VS2008. I have yyy.h like header files around 20 in for which I am do not know the paths. Its a huge project and got around 50 project files included in it.

Comment: Worst case, you can copy the one declaration you need over into your own code.

Comment: Then I suggest you find out which of 20 files you actually need, and either point your compiler to the directory or change your xxx.h header to include it with a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `#ifdef` blocks to prevent the unwanted headers to be included.

Lets say you need a a prototype of a function , other than this you do not need anything. Then :

```
#ifndef MY_APP
#include <notneeded1.h>
#include <notneeded2.h>
.............
.............
#endif
#ifdef MY_APP
void my_needed_foo_bar()
#endif

#ifndef MY_APP
.....
#endif
```

Now compile your app with defining MY_APP

Like in gcc

```
$gcc -DMY_APP ....
```